# Selecting from multiple SLURM GPU resources

Tags: gpu, slurm

I'm submitting jobs to a cluster via SLURM scheduler, and let's say I have access to 5 types of GPUs in my cluster. They are GPUs of type A,B,C,D,E. I would like to submit a job that requests the use of GPUs of type A or B or C but NOT of type D or E. So I need some type of OR logic with the `--gres` flag.

As a concrete example, here is what it looks like when I request a gpu of a single type (in this case, an RTX 2080):
`qlogin -p gpu --gres=gpu:rtx2080:1 --mem=8g -c 2` I'd like to do this but allowing SLURM to pick from a list of allowed GPU types

Answer (score 3):

Slurm does not have that option at this time.

One workaround is for the system administrator to setup `features` of the node with the GPU type to allow a request such as:

```
qlogin -p gpu --gres=gpu:1 --constraint="rtx2080|rtx3090" --mem=8g -c 2
```

(assuming `qlogin` uses the same  options as `sbatch`)

If that is not possible, you can submit as many job as there are types of GPU that you want, all with the same `--job-name=<SOME_NAME>` and the `--dependency=singleton` option. Then you use whichever job starts first and cancel the other with

```
scancel --jobname <SOME_NAME> --state=PENDING
```

The `--dependency` option makes sure only one job is started at a time.